# Usage of Exigo, Exigere

Tags: vocabulary

Can the verb "exigo, exigere, exegi, exactum," be used to mean "that man will pull through, despite his many injuries?"

Wheelocks' translation allows for the meanings of "drive through, complete, perfect." I'm trying to get a good grasp of the verb, so this might help.

Answer (score 2):

To get a good grasp of the verb, I recommend taking a look at what [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=exigo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) have to say about it.
The verb has a very broad array of meanings, not all clearly connected to being the combination of *ex* and *agere*.
The one most relevant for your question seems to be meaning II.B.8, "to endure".
Also the meanings "drive through, complete, perfect" appear in the entry in L&S.

If you want us to help study the possible meanings of the verb in some specific context, I recommend asking a separate question about a sentence or a passage.